# Add clickable stamp annotation PSPDFKit

Tags: android, pdf, pspdfkit, pdf-annotations

I am using **PSPDFKit** to manipulate PDF files. The point of my application is to add a **stamp** onto a PDF, which works perfectly fine. But, I would like to make my stamps clickable so I might click on it from another PDF Viewer (such as Acrobat).

I though of many ways to do it but the only one plausible is to make my stamps clickables.

I'm adding a stamp thanks to PSPDFKit **UI** but I'm implementing my custom logic in order to handle the annotation creation.

```
    pdfDocument.getAnnotationProvider().addOnAnnotationUpdatedListener(new AnnotationProvider.OnAnnotationUpdatedListener(){
            //I check if this is the first Stamp annotation I created for this session. 
            //If it isn't I just move the  previous one to the new point
            //Each time I open my PDF I can add only one stamp annotation
            @Override
            public void onAnnotationCreated(@NonNull com.pspdfkit.annotations.Annotation annotation) {
                if(annotation instanceof StampAnnotation){
                    if(currentAnnotation != null){
                        if(fragment.getDocument() != null) {
                            fragment.getDocument().getAnnotationProvider().removeAnnotationFromPage(annotation);
                            fragment.notifyAnnotationHasChanged(annotation);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        ((StampAnnotation) annotation).setSubtext(currentImageName);
                        currentAnnotation = annotation;
                    }
                    /*
                      Trying to find how to make currentAnnotation a clickable annotation
                      I used the subtext attribute to store some data relevant for my action.
                      I also looked up for LinkAnnotations but I can't figure how they work out
                    */
                }
            }

            //I check if the annotation is a Stamp. 
            //If it is, I add it to annotations to remove from my app's business logic
            @Override
            public void onAnnotationRemoved(@NonNull com.pspdfkit.annotations.Annotation annotation) {
                if(annotation instanceof StampAnnotation){
                    runOnUiThread(() ->Toast.makeText(PSPdfFloorPlanActivity.this, "Annotation removed " + ((StampAnnotation) annotation).getSubtext(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
                    if(annotation.equals(currentAnnotation)){
                        currentAnnotation = null;
                    }

                    removedAnnotationsImagesNames.add(((StampAnnotation) annotation).getSubtext());
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance,
if the question seems to broad comment it I'm trying to make is as simple as possible to understand ^^

Cordially,
Matthieu

Comment: Please reach out via https://pspdfkit.com/support/request/ and our support team will help - thank you!

Comment: I just did, without being sure it was the right place to do so.